# Após adicionar um pacote como dependência em outro projeto, problemas de referências persistem

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, packages

Tendo criado um pacote e logo após referenciá-lo como dependência em um projeto, que se encontra no mesmo grupo de projetos, tenho problemas ao tentar usar as referências de **`unit`** contidas no pacote. Mesmo após a adição da dependência.

Mesmo após compilar e mandar instalar o pacote, o erro continua.

Como esta minha estrutura do grupo de projetos e o modo como referencio:

[image: Estrutura de projetos]

Aqui eu marco a dependência:

[image: Dependência marcada]

Inclusive naveguei até o diretório indicado pela imagem (**`C:\Users\Public\Documents\RadStudio\10.0\Bpl\`**) e lá esta o arquivo `ORM.bpl`.

Mas ao tentar utilizar as unit´s que estariam já compilados no pacote, não consigo:

[image: biblioteca referenciada]

Esse é o erro ao tentar compilar:

[image: Erro ao tentar compilar]

Sempre que precisava associar as bibliotecas de outros pacotes, mesmo tendo instalado eles na IDE do Delphi, eu sempre precisei adicionar a ***unit*** no projeto ou nas pastas pesquisadas pelo Delphi (***Libraries***).

Logo eu pergunto se nesse tipo de caso a referência de dependencias não adianta em nada e então qual o objetivo dessa referência?

Ou então, claro, se fui eu quem fez ou deixei de fazer algo?

Comment: Saudades de programar em Delphi.

Comment: Passou. Ainda bem.

Comment: @Cigano, Hehehe... Eu ainda não posso me dar a esse luxo! =D
Ainda tenho muitos projetos que preciso dar manutenção, mas a equipe onde trabalho esta mudando e eu estou pegando uns projetos ASP.NET com C#, o que já dá uma felicidade =D, as coisas se tornam possível sem muito sofrimento.

Comment: Opa, apenas uma tentativa, vou pesquisar melhor no intervalo do almoço, mas em **Project -> Option -> Package -> RunTime Packages** tente adicionar o seu pacote lá e veja se funciona sem as dcu's. Pelo que vi, precisaria de um dcp como pode ver [neste link](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_Packages)

Comment: @Caputo, logo mais quando eu tiver um tempo, eu testo. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @Caputo, finalmente testei... Oo ... então, mesmo colocando o pacote na lista de pacotes como você sugeriu, e setando as configurações do pacote como apenas runtime (conforme indicação do link) para não precisar de instalação na IDE, ainda não funcionou. Ou seja, ainda reclama não encontrar a biblioteca.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você marca como dependência o Delphi ira somente compilar o ORM.bpl antes dele.

O que você deve fazer é adicionar o DCP do pacote ORM em `Runtime packages`. Para isso entre em `Options` de seu projeto e procure por `Runtime packages`.
[image: Runtime packages]

Lembrando que caso esteja usando uma versão `Delphi XE` ou superior, tem que se atentar para o `Target`.

Um coisa importante, se você estiver tentando enviar a `.bpl` separado do arquivo compilado deve marcar a opção `Link with runtime packages` como `True`.